# Magento on localhost forwarding to live site

Tags: magento-1.9, database, localhost

I have installed Magento using MAMP for access on a localhost (as to not touch the live site).

I have then imported the database to duplicate the live site and have changed the username/password etc in `local.xml`.

The problem I have is that every time I try and visit my local site it redirects me to the live site.

I have gone into my /private/etc/hosts through Terminal and have added the line: 127.0.0.1 http://localhost/magento but I still can't get it to work.

Every time I visit http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php it forwards to the live site.

Does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 4):

Check the table 'core_config_data' and seach for paths '`web/secure/base_url' and 'web/unsecure/base_url'.` They should point to your local site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked for those files and don't have them :/ the closest I have is: web/secure/base_link_url and web/unsecure/base_link_url

Comment: They could also be set in the local.xml and related.

Comment: Can't see anything in my local.xml file. Perhaps I can just create these files that are missing in the database?

Comment: That would probably help. However I think it's a ggood idea to scan the xml files/database for your live url.
Maybe you should scan your server rewrites (e.g. .htaccess) as well.

Comment: Okay, here's what I done: I put all the Magento core files back (removed all the backed up files) and just changed the database information to be that of the database only. As soon as I changed the database information it redirected back to the live site, so I think i'm right in thinking that the problem lies in the database. The only item in the database that has the live site is for 'cookies'.

Comment: clear cache folder at var

Comment: Tried that Amit; unfortunately that didn't do the trick

Comment: Eugh, just found the web/secure/base_url file - did NOT realize that the database only searched 1 page when doing a search. Eugh! Hopefully this works....

Comment: That worked! Thank you all! So many hours of frustration for something so silly.

Comment: Okay, new problem (I might need to create a new thread for this): it's now referencing none of my files (i.e. all my skin / images are missing). It just shows the text of the database. Perhaps I did my path's wrong: 'http://localhost/magento/' ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things to check for this, most have been covered, but the really tricky ones you won't find in most places.

#### Most Common

---

- A redirect, such as an apache server hidden
  .htaccess or an nginx configuration file location block.
- Second most common is that you've done everything correctly, but not
  cleared the cache. You can just delete the entire 'var' folder at the
  web root, it will be recreated when you visit the site in your
  browser.

**Notes**: Var folder permissions may be 777. Via terminal this is 'chmod -R 777 var' if you are in your web root.

> The above instructions are assuming you've already completed the usual actions. Next are those actions, and some oddities.

#### Database

---

All stock changes are in the 'core_config_data' table. Under 'path' column check the following and adjust their data in the 'value' column:

- web/unsecure/base_url
- web/secure/base_url

**Format**: protocol://youraddress.whatever/ - with trailing slash

> **Example**: http://abc.dev/

**TRICKY: Be sure to pay careful attention to https, vs http. Often you need to change the https to http.**

**TRICKY: Some Magento installs have multiple stores. Multiple stores will have multiple web secure urls set. Be sure to change them all- this one is easy to miss. Usually I just search the value column for the url, or a piece of it, to find all of them.**

#### Cookie Domain

---

**TRICKY: This one is often not mentioned as its very uncommon, but check the 'path' column for 'web/cookie/cookie_domain'. If this is set to a url, set it to your new url in the same format.**

> **Example**: www.site.com becomes www.site.dev

Answer (score 1):

**Post answered:**

I just needed to update the `web/secure/base_link_url` and `web/unsecure/base_link_url` in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change database setting in your PHPMYADMIN.

just find `core_config_data` table.

and change `web/unsecure/base_url` value URL.
and change `web/secure/base_url` value URL.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table '`core_config_data`' and search for paths '**web/secure/base_url**' and '**web/unsecure/base_url**'. They should point to your local site.

and also clear the cache and try it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was config with `path=payment/wayforpay_payment/merchant` which has old domain with dots replaced by underscores, e.g. `www_yourdomain_com`. After I changed it to `mynewdomain_com` issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and solved it using following steps.

**1. Change base_url**

Navigate to the `core_config_data` table in your database and add
    your store url to the value column of following `path` column.

```
web/secure/base_url
web/secure/base_link_url
web/unsecure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_link_url
```

**2. Clear log entries**

Run following SQL query in order to truncate log tables.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Change `base_url` in `core_config_data`

**Step 2:** Remove page Cache.  `rm -rf var/page_cache/*`

**Step 3:** Change Cookie domain in `core_config_data`. Check cookie domain  `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path ='web/cookie/cookie_domain';`

Answer (score 0):

You can try flash redis in case the other solutions don't work

`redis-cli flushall`